# How to change backgroundcolor of QLineEdit in a QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsscene, qlineedit

I have a `QGraphicsScene` and add a `QlineEdit` but changing color just doesn't work.

```
QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout(this);
QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView(this);
QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);

QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
QGridLayout *widgetLayout = new QGridLayout(this);
QLineEdit *le1 = new QLineEdit(widget);
QLineEdit *le2 = new QLineEdit(widget);
widgetLayout->addWidget(le1,1,0);
widgetLayout->addWidget(le2,2,0);
widget->setLayout(widgetLayout);



QPalette paletteRed = le1->palette();
paletteRed.setColor(QPalette::Background,Qt::red);

QPalette paletteGreen = le1->palette();
paletteGreen.setColor(QPalette::Background,Qt::green);


le1->setAutoFillBackground(true);
le1->setPalette(paletteRed); // not working
widget->setPalette(paletteGreen); // working


view->setScene(scene);
scene->addWidget(widget);

ui->centralWidget->setLayout(layout);
layout->addWidget(view);
```

Do I have to trigger something like `update()` ( which is not working either to get another color ) if the widget is in a scene?

**EDIT:**

created new example Code.

I know this works in a normal `QWidget`.  Actually the code works fine if i place the `QLineEdit` in a normal `QFrame`etc **but** its in a `QGraphicsScene`. And in this special case its not working. Text and highlight color etc is also working fine. But backgroud/base/etc ist not.

Comment: Where is the color changing code ?

Comment: Changeing `QPallette` ?

Comment: Try to use qt style sheets

Comment: Its not like ich cant change anything, i can change `Text` color but i cant change `background' or 'base'

Comment: did you solve the problem? i have the same problem when placing a lineedit in a textedit

Comment: No, still searching

Answer (score 1):

> Setting background color via QPalette does not for my widget, why?

Usually it is `autoFillBackground` property not set to true to allow setting background on its own.

```
QPalette palette = pWidget->palette(); // fixed it (need to initialize)
palette.setColor(pWidget->backgroundRole(), bkgndColor); // for background (fixed)
palette.setColor(pWidget->foregroundRole(), fgrndColor); // for foreground
pWidget->setAutoFillBackground(true); // to allow to fill the background
pWidget->setPalette(palette);
```

Setting the background via stylesheet may also work because it forces `autoFillBackground == true` mode.

Comment: `QPalette::Background` should be replaced by `pWidget->backgroundRole()`. Info here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#backgroundRole

Comment: @JonHarper Right, that is better to get actual background role. Making fixes in my own code then. SO rules!

Comment: @AlexanderVX this istn working. It is working in normal cases like for `QFrame` and also for `QLineInput` if used in a normal widget. But if i put in a `QGraphicsScene` it is not working

Comment: @J.W. There is one suspicious thing in your code, though: QPalette pal(QApplication::palette()); Can you try with QLineEdit own palette?

Comment: @J.W. Try capturing the pointer to the `QGraphicsProxyWidget` that is returned from `addWidget` and set the palette on that.

Comment: @AlexanderVX Its not making any difference. I tryed but its not working either. I posted a new example code.

Comment: @JonHarper Thats not working either, neverless if it had worked i still need to change the background color for a special `QLineEdit` and not all

Comment: @J.W. I cannot see le1->setAutoFillBackground(true) there.

Comment: @AlexanderVW cause its not working and doesnt make any difference

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest a slight modification on AlexanderVX's answer. In the first line I would write:

```
QPalette palette = pWidget->palette();
```

Just to make sure you tune just what you need of the base object palette.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I had an similar issue where the background-color just colored the outline:

[image]

the problem was that there was an border-image set. After setting `border-image: none;` the background color showed up